# How to display products on a homepage in a list mode in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-list, widget, list.phtml, category-view

I tried to use Catalog Products list to display products on my homepage (not category page). By default, all products are shown in grid mode. And I see that there is only one option of grid mode in grid.phtml file.

I'd like to add a list mode as an option or make it as default.

As an alternative solution, I used the following code

`{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" category_id="35" product_count="10" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml"}}`

to display the products in a list mode. That worked well. However, pictures don't show up. I don't why.

**I'll be grateful for any advice**.

Comment: Please check in product assign image or not ?